# android: how to find out non touch sensitive padding of device

Tags: android, touch, screen, device

For a drawing app, I have to make sure that the canvas is not bigger then the touchable area of the screen, cause otherwise I would have a padding on the canvas, where it is not possible for the user to draw on.

On my Galaxy S that's about 10 pixel I guess. 
Is there a way to find out the exact number of pixels which are not touch-sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but that has no sense . I think that maybe components are not good enough , but the screen in android must have the capability to touch all window places .

If you have the reason and the producer make that horrible mistake , program thinking that you don't have the whole touchable area , you would make a bad thing for producers that do it well.

Anyway if you are thinking in usability for users , don't work with pixels , work with dip .

Comment: I heard something that this is design by purpose (from an iOS dev): if the touchable area would reach out right to the borders of the screen, you would touch areas by accident when holding the device in your hand. This might not be true for every device, but at least for some with a big screen (like iphone, galaxy s,...)